# Cast/Convert Text-Decimal

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, type-conversion

I know this is bad practice but its the only way i can do it due to the data migration column requirements.

I am looking to round up(CEIL) or round down (FLOOR) my value in a text feild.

I know for a fact they are all either integers or decimals so no worry about bad data there.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[T01]
SET [2 37] =    CAST(
             FLOOR(CONVERT(decimal(10,5),(CAST([2 37] AS varchar(10)))))
             AS text )
WHERE [2 37] LIKE '%.%'
```

My first attempt was:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Tomcat 19032013 01]
SET [2 37] = FLOOR([2 37])
WHERE [2 37] LIKE '%.%'
```

Long story short i want to be able to floor or ceil that data in my text field!

I am using SQL 2005 - Developer Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add columns to do the conversion.

```
DECLARE @T01 TABLE([2 37] text, [2 37 Floor] int, [2 37 Ceiling] int)
INSERT @T01 ([2 37]) VALUES('1.5')
INSERT @T01 ([2 37]) VALUES('4.1')
INSERT @T01 ([2 37]) VALUES('5.9')

update t
set [2 37 Floor]=floor(CONVERT(decimal(8,2),(CAST([2 37] AS varchar(10))))  )
,  [2 37 Ceiling] =ceiling(CONVERT(decimal(8,2),(CAST([2 37] AS varchar(10)))))
from @T01 t
WHERE [2 37] LIKE '%.%'
select * from @T01
```

Comment: Oh i so agree with this, 2 new columns and leave the TEXT column alone, it seems like you have an unnecessary conversion to varchar(10)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, you are right, I was orginally trying something else and forgot to remove the extra cast.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to round off the value to nearest integer

Rounding down

```
UPDATE [dbo].[T01]
SET [2 37] =
CAST(CAST(FLOOR(CONVERT(decimal(10,5),(CAST([2 37] AS varchar(10))))) as VARCHAR(10))
AS text )
WHERE [2 37] LIKE '%.%'
```

Rounding up

```
UPDATE [dbo].[T01]
SET [2 37] =    CAST(
CAST(CEILING(
CONVERT(decimal(10,5),(CAST([2 37] AS varchar(10))))) as VARCHAR(10))
AS text )
WHERE [2 37] LIKE '%.%'
```

Comment: Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Explicit conversion from data type decimal to text is not allowed.

Comment: Would you be able to provide example for both floor and ceil

Comment: @Lmc example included

Comment: I dont see floor or ceil been used though and that is needed

Comment: @LmC it is rounding off to nearest whole, that is what i assumed you needed. Isn't this the result you needed ?

Comment: @LmC Please provide sample data and expected result if this is not what you want.

Comment: E.g 3.1 may be asked to go to 3 or 4 so thats why i was looking to round up and round down

Comment: @LmC what determines rounding up or down ? a variable or a column

Comment: Me, The person doing it so there would be 2 querys one for up one for down sorry for confusion